# Is there anyway to put a QTreeView and a QChartView in the same window in qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

Exactly as it says. I know it might seem rather trivial, but I am new to Qt in general and I can't seem to find a similar case. And I don't know if I can use QSplitter since it requires a QWidget and QTreeView isn't one.

Edit:
The code I am trying to use

```
QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(pie);
QTreeView treeView;
QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter;
splitter->addWidget(treeView);
splitter->addWidget(chartView);
QMainWindow window;
window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
```

Comment: Note that [`QTreeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) *is* a `QWidget`.

Comment: will qt creator specifically tells me that it isn't

'main.cpp:63:25: error: no viable conversion from 'QTreeView' to 'QWidget *''
'qsplitter.h:71:29: note: passing argument to parameter 'widget' here'

I don't really get it to be honest

Comment: That error message means you are trying to use a `QTreeView` where you should probably be using a `QTreeView *`.  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I believe the easiest way to do it is via designer. Generate ui from cpp code isn't the best idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it's the pointer. Thank you @G.M.
QSplitter seems to work with pointers to objects not objects.